# Why do we have to pass "this" parameter in foo.call(this, param1, param2)?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

As far as I know we use `foo.call()` to chain constructors for an object. E.g. the following:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}
function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

function Toy(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'toy';
}

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
```

Instead of using `call()` method, we could have directly inserted the `Product`'s code as:

```
function Food(name, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = 'food';
    }

    function Toy(name, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = 'toy';
    }

    var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
    var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
```

As far as I know foo() executes the function. So instead of `Product.call(this, name, price);` if we directly call the function as `Product(name , price)` then this must equivalent to write `this.name = name; this.price = price;`

- So why doesn't adding `Product(name , price)` directly assign `name` to `this.name`, that is `cheese.name` and `fun.name`?

If for some reason we have to use the call method then why do we pass `this` parameter to call method? Why don't we instead use `Product.call(name, price)`?

Comment: Because that's how the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works (inside the `Product` function)

Comment: @Bergi To what does `this` refer to inside `Product`?

Comment: Nothing, if you called it as `Product(name, price)`. To the `this` that you passed in via `call` when you called it as `Product.call(this, name, price)` - i.e. the `this` that is the new toy or food.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions are executed within a certain context.  Depending on how a function is called (there are four ways), `this` is assigned a certain value.

One way is to call a stand-alone function.  In non-strict mode, if you call `Product(name, price)` from within the body of `Food`, `this` is assigned the value of the `global` (or `window`) object.  The value of `name` will be assigned to the global variable `name`, etc., and not to the `this` object being constructed inside `Food` method.

In strict mode, if you do the same as above, `this` is assigned the value `null` or `undefined`, so you will get an error.

Another way is to call a function using the primitive method `call`, which allows us to provide the correct value for the `this` object by passing it as the first argument to the `call` method.

If we do not use `call`, `this` will not be a reference to the correct object.

Comment: I guess `this` is assigned the correct value only if it is one scope inside. In `function('my_name'){ this.name = my_name }` would work but in `function('my_name'){ Product (my_name){ this.name = my_name} }` The `this` can't look two scopes above.